# T-SQL query runs very slowly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query that is taking, what I think to be abnormally long, so I am changing around things and trying different things to speed it up. Currently it is taking between 3 and 4 minutes to return less than 11k records.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @PtVistitOID TABLE (
    PatientVisitOID INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @PtVistitOID
    SELECT DISTINCT PatientVisitOID
    FROM smsdss.c_covid_ptvisitoid_tbl
    WHERE PatientVisitOID IS NOT NULL

SELECT 
    A.OBJECTID AS PatientVisit_OID,
    A.PATIENTACCOUNTID,
    A.PatientVisitExtension_OID
FROM
    [SC_server].[Soarian_Clin_Prd_1].DBO.HPatientVisit AS A
INNER JOIN 
    [SC_server].[Soarian_Clin_Prd_1].dbo.HExtendedPatientVisit AS B ON A.PatientVisitExtension_OID = B.objectid
INNER JOIN 
    @PtVistitOID AS C ON A.ObjectID = C.PatientVisitOID
--WHERE A.ObjectID IN (SELECT PatientVisitOID FROM @PtVistitOID);
```

When I check the estimated query execution plan, it says that roughly 95% of the time is spent inserting records into the table `@PtVisitOID`, this portion of the query will run as fast as you can click execute, there are 13,970 rows in `@PtVisitOID`. So the remaining 5% is from the rest of the query. The entire query is taking again between 3 and 4 minutes.

All of the joins are on columns of exactly the same type, INT.

I can select records from all of the individual tables rather quickly, less than 5 seconds. It is specifically when I add the last `INNER JOIN` or if I change it to a `WHERE A.ObjectID IN (SELECT PatientVisitOID FROM @PtVisitOID)` that the query time blows up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please tell, how many records are in the  @PtVistitOID

Comment: I will edit the question to reflect this info, 13,970

Comment: Some tables are from linked server? You should try `remote join` hints somewhere; currently all remote records are probaly read to current database and joined here.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Have you tried using a temp table instead of a table variable?

Comment: @dfundako I have, I even have the data in a table itself, still same problem, and it seems it is just with this query. Could be the linked server against a data warehouse, not sure

Comment: `@table` variables perform horribly on older versions of SQL Server because they're always estimated as containing 1 row. Consider using a `#temp` table instead, possibly with `update statistics #PtVistitOID with fullscan` after inserting into it but before using it in the select statement.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I think thats probably it. Table variables and linked servers combined is a recipe for slowness.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning tied your suggestion, still 3 minutes. Going to have to brainstorm this one

Comment: It's implied that join columns should also have indexes on them. If you check your Actual Execution Plan you'll probably see a bunch of table scans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restructured how I write the query and am happy to note that execution time went down to between 1 and 2 seconds. I do pull back less records but this is good as the others that are no longer coming back are useless. That in of itself is not the reason for the speed up, the restructure is.

```
DECLARE @PtVistitOID TABLE (
    PatientVisitOID INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @PtVistitOID
SELECT DISTINCT PatientVisitOID
FROM smsdss.c_covid_ptvisitoid_tbl
WHERE PatientVisitOID IS NOT NULL

DECLARE @UserDefinedString TABLE (
    PatientVisit_OID INT,
    PatientAccountID INT,
    Covid_Indicator VARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @UserDefinedString
SELECT A.OBJECTID AS PatientVisit_OID,
    A.PATIENTACCOUNTID,
    --A.PatientVisitExtension_OID,
    B.UserDefinedString20
FROM [SC_server].[Soarian_Clin_Prd_1].DBO.HPatientVisit AS A
INNER JOIN [SC_server].[Soarian_Clin_Prd_1].dbo.HExtendedPatientVisit AS B ON A.PatientVisitExtension_OID = B.objectid
WHERE A.PatientVisitExtension_OID IS NOT NULL
AND B.UserDefinedString20 IS NOT NULL
AND B.UserDefinedString20 != ''

SELECT A.PatientVisitOID,
B.PatientAccountID,
B.Covid_Indicator
FROM @PtVistitOID AS A
INNER JOIN @UserDefinedString AS B
ON A.PatientVisitOID = B.PatientVisit_OID
```

By taking the suggestion of not mixing local and linked server tables, by choosing to make results all inside of local @tables the speedup desired was achieved.

Comment: Any reason you are using a table variable in the first place, couldn't you just put the two queries in derived subqueries?

Comment: I could but this runs as fast as I can click execute so why bother? This was quick to write and just as easy to follow